# Rider treats freshly checked out Projekt as "All files are new"

Tags: tfs, rider

I am using the TFS Integration Plugin, as the built in TFS Connection somehow is not able to connect to our TFS. With the same login/path I am able to check out projects from our TFS but then Rider treets the freshly checked out project as "not under version control" and does not recognize any changes.

[image]

I can add them all to version control and after that Rider recognizes changes in files. But it also still thinks that all other files are new, which is really not the case. In this picture, I added all files and changed one.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here, as I am used to VS/TFS Version Control or might this be a bug? I asked the same thing in the community forum, but there is no real activity...

Answer (score 1):

Have tested installing `riderRS-171.4456.902.exe` (Windows), the TFS Integration plugin has been bundled with Rider and enabled VCS-TFVC successfully. And it can detect the changes correctly. Please follow below requirements:

> You must have the [TF command line tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases) installed to be able to use
>   TFVC features. The minimum version supported by the plugin is `14.0.3`.
>   To install the tool, download the latest "`TEE-CLC-14...zip`" file and
>   extract it to a known location. After extracting the files, you must
>   accept the license agreement. To do so, open a Command Prompt/Terminal
>   window, navigate to the extracted directory, and run  `tf eula`. After
>   reading the EULA, enter y enter code hereto accept it. **NOTE**: If you
>   forget to do this, the plugin may fail to load with a
>   RuntimeException.

For the tool to be detected by the plugin, you must set the location of the executable in the Settings/Preferences menu by following these instructions:

1. Go to RD Settings Version Control -TFVC
2. In the **Path to tf executable** text field, navigate to the location of
   the tf executable.
3. Click **Test** to test that the executable has been found and is working
   as expected.
4. Click **Apply** then **OK** to save and exit.

Also check below things:

> If TFVC does not come up as your version control system (VCS) then it
>   can be set manually. Go to the `VCS` dropdown menu in the toolbar and
>   select `Enable Version Control Integration`. Select `TFVC` from the
>   dropdown menu and click `OK`.

More details please refer this [tutorial](http://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/tools/intelliJ#_tfvc-support).

Please try to setup a new created project or select another project when you are using Rider with TFS. To narrow down if the issue is related to that special project.

[image]

Comment: I had allready done all that, that did not really help. With TFVC and GIT is the problem, that i can not log in, whatsoever. This is the reason i tried TFS Integration. I found out, that the reason for this weird behaviour is that i used the VS Workspace, where Rider does not recognize any changes. After all the Integration Plugin crashes frequently and i always have to restart Rider to make a new checkin. Also it took rider 4-5 hours to scan a project for changes on the first opening. It is just a pain, i do not get how it can be that hard to implement a working TFS Integration...

Comment: @Simons0n So, have you resolved the issue by creating a new workspace for Rider?

Comment: No, not really, it is still a very unpleasing experience. But yes, the original question shoould be solved if I do not use the VS worspace and if I am willing to wati 3-4 hours for the changes to be recognized. Details of my other problems are https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000466450-Not-able-to-connect-to-TFS-
 and here https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000478210-TFS-Checkin-Policies-not-fullfillable 
No support from jetbrains whatsoever.... Really frustrating

Comment: @Simons0n Based on my test, everything works well with the Rider workspace, the first time it will spend much time to scan all the files and identify the changes. If the project is a large one, then the period will be longer. And after that, everything is OK. So, I suggest you try the latest Rider with a new workspace.